# Copy the Data from nested Source Directory to Destination Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm Just started learning python and stuck in getting any idea on the below Situation hope you will forget my silly mistakes.

I have Directory path `/home/sysmgt/rmlogs/` which has further Directories my month names,As i have a Directory for month January and this Directory again contains multiple directories for the January month by date-wise and these Directories lastly containing the multiple files by systems-names with `text` extensions. So, What I'm trying to achieve is to do traverse into the Directory by the Current month and copy all of the contents of txt files into one file on the Destination Dir say `/scratch/rm_logs/` but as this will be a script running every interval so need to check if the already copied data contents(file contents) could not overwritten.

```
$ cd /home/sysmgt/rmlogs/

[karn@noi-karn rmlogs]$ ls -ltrh | tail

drwxr-xr-x 70 nfsnobody nfsnobody 8.0K Nov 25 17:04 November
drwxr-xr-x 88 nfsnobody nfsnobody 8.0K Dec 16 15:38 June
drwxr-xr-x 33 nfsnobody nfsnobody 4.0K Dec 25 05:12 December
drwxr-xr-x 11 nfsnobody nfsnobody 4.0K Jan  8 15:01 January
drwxr-xr-x 62 nfsnobody nfsnobody 8.0K Jan  8 15:37 July


$ cd January
$ ls -ltrh
total 1.9M
drwxrwxrwx 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 228K Jan  1 23:59 Jan_01_19
drwxrwxrwx 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 228K Jan  2 23:59 Jan_02_19
drwxrwxrwx 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 228K Jan  3 23:59 Jan_03_19
drwxrwxrwx 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 228K Jan  4 23:59 Jan_04_19
drwxrwxrwx 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 228K Jan  5 23:59 Jan_05_19
drwxrwxrwx 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 228K Jan  6 23:59 Jan_06_19
drwxrwxrwx 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 228K Jan  7 23:59 Jan_07_19
drwxr-xr-x 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 4.0K Jan  8 15:01 Jan_15_19
drwxrwxrwx 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 228K Jan  8 16:18 Jan_08_19


$ cd Jan_08_19
$ ls -ltrh| tail
-rw-r--r-- 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody  26K Jan  8 16:03 dbfchw091.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody  238 Jan  8 16:07 dbfcnl030.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody  695 Jan  8 16:10 dbfcib069.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody 1.6K Jan  8 16:13 dbfchw126.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody  401 Jan  8 16:13 dbfcib001.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody 7.0K Jan  8 16:15 dbfcsb003.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody  44K Jan  8 16:16 klno-foxvcron-in2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody 3.7K Jan  8 16:17 dbfcnl059.txt
```

I tried using `glob` & `shutil.copy()` but did not get it.

```
>>> for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join("/home/sysmgt/rmlogs/January/"*.*"/*.txt")):
...     shutil.copy(filename, "/scratch/rm_logs/")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Comment: You are trying to multiply the path with the name of the file. You can only multiply a string by an integer, what did you want to achive with that multiplication?

Comment: @PSM, Sorry, i mean it was wildcard.

Comment: Have you tried `os.path.join("/home/sysmgt/rmlogs/January/*/*.txt")` ?

Comment: You should try `glob.glob(os.path.join("/home/sysmgt/rmlogs/January/", "*/*.txt"))` or `glob.glob("/home/sysmgt/rmlogs/January/*/*.txt")`.

Comment: @PSM , thats works but it now it over-rides if i will run it again , thnx for correcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
for filename in glob.glob("/home/sysmgt/rmlogs/January/*/*.txt"):
    shutil.copy(filename, "/scratch/rm_logs/")
```

If you want to avoid if over writing the files when running it a second time you can do:

```
for filename in glob.glob("/home/sysmgt/rmlogs/January/*/*.txt"):
    if not os.path.exists("/scratch/rm_logs/" + os.path.basename(filename)):
        shutil.copy(filename, "/scratch/rm_logs/")
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer but i'm looking for an idea , How to make sure even if file changed then only append the changed content dont override.